# Expectation of biased coefficient in linear model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression

Given the following regression model:

$$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_T x_{ij} + \beta_L(x_{ij} - x_{i1}) + \epsilon_{ij}$$

I need to find the expectation of $\hat \beta$, given by:
$\hat \beta = (X'X)^{-1}(X'y)$. So:

$$ E[\hat \beta] = E[(X'X)^{-1}(X'y)]$$
$$ E[\hat \beta] = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_{ij}'x_{ij})^{-1}
\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_{ij}'E[y_{ij}]) $$
$$ E[\hat \beta] = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_{ij}'x_{ij})^{-1}
\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_{ij}'(\beta_0 + \beta_T x_{ij} + \beta_L(x_{ij} - x_{i1}))) $$

What I did was:

1. Divide and multiplicate by $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_{ij})$:
   $$ E[\hat \beta] = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}\beta_0 + \beta_T x_{ij} + \beta_L(x_{ij} - x_{i1})}{\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_{ij})} $$
2. Remove the sums where I can:

$$ E[\hat \beta] = \frac{(N*n)\beta_0}{\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_{ij})} + (\beta_T + \beta_L)  - \beta_L \sum_{i = 1}^{N} n * x_{i1}$$

And this is where I'm stuck. Also, I don't think everything I did is right. I called the coefficient "biased" because the teacher told me I would verify that.